# MySQL root@localhost, root@127.0.0.1 and root@::1 have different passwords - is it normal?

Tags: mysql, mysqladmin

After setting password with this command:

```
mysqladmin.exe --user=root password <my_password>
```

I see 3 rows in user table for "root" user:
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Rkd.jpg
and root@localhost has password, while root@127.0.0.1 and root@::1 do not have password.

Does it mean that I need to set password 3 times for each of these rows? i.e.:

```
mysqladmin.exe --user=root host=localhost password <my_password>
mysqladmin.exe --user=root host=127.0.0.1 password <my_password>
mysqladmin.exe --user=root host=::1 password <my_password>
```

Is this normal?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is different accounts. And yes, every account can have own password. You can check details about account names [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html).
If you don't set host with mysql utilities (such as mysqladmin), by default it will connect to localhost. So, you was really connected under user `root@localhost` and changed password for this user only. For two other `root` users you must change password explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

::1 is the IPV6 IP address of 127.0.0.1 (which is IPV4), which is also localhost.